# Why is css not working as expected with Omega

Tags: theming

Making site with left side menu items built on Omega responsive grid. Setting up the global.css to theme out some page elements, like this menu.

Problem: Used css not used in the browser. Instead system.menus.css is used.
Question: Why.

CSS: for menu

```
/*============== Menu Items ====================*/
.menu ul
{
    padding:8px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#FFF;
    list-style:none;
    text-indent:15px;
    background:#0000a2;
}
.menu ul li
{
    background:#0000a2;
    line-height:28px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background:#3ea5ea;
}
.menu ul li#active
{
    background:#3ea5ea;
}

====================================

Chrome inspector data:
media="all"
ul.menu {
border: none;
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
}
dea.harland.tkmedia="all"
.menu {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
dea.harland.tkmedia="all"
p, dl, hr, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, ul, pre, table, address, fieldset {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
dea.harland.tkmedia="all"
ul {
list-style: disc;
}
user agent stylesheetul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

Inherited from `body.html.front.logged-in.page-node.toolbar.toolbar-drawer.omega-mediaqueries-processed.omega-equalheights-processed.alpha-debug-processed.responsive-layout-wide`

```
dea.harland.tkmedia="all"
body {
font: 0.75em/1.3em Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
dea.harland.tkmedia="all"
body {
font: 13px/1.5 Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Is there a live/demo site we can refer to?

Comment: Yes, dea.harland.tk

Answer (score 2):

I think your CSS is incorrect. You wrote:

```
.menu ul li {/*stuff*/}
```

when I think it needs to be:

```
ul.menu li {/*stuff*/}
```

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Looks better already. There U go when copying from so called css authorities on the www. Thanks. I thought is was correct css but apparently it is not.

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to see if the element you want has the class you're targeting. If this answer works, feel free to mark it as so. ;)